# Mostly liked / most liked / liked mostly / liked most

Tags: sentence-construction

> A) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places mostly liked by people living in urban areas.

Is the above sentence correct ?

What about the constructions given below ?

> B) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places most liked by people living in urban areas.
>
> C) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places liked mostly by people living in urban areas.
>
> D) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places  liked most by people living in urban areas.

Which of these construction is correct ?

I would like to put forward my understanding of above sentences, I guess using *most* in the sentence implies among other places liked by people living in urban areas forests , rivers etc are most liked by them ( liked more as compared to other places) while using *mostly* implies rivers, mountains and forests are liked mainly by people living in areas. ( may or may not be liked by people living in other areas) But what about the placement of most/mostly ? Which is the correct construction ?

Answer (score 1):

> A) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places mostly liked by people living in urban areas.

This implies that [urbanites](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/urbanite) don't *completely* like rivers, mountains, and forests.  ("mostly" is being applied to "like".)

> B) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places most liked by people living in urban areas.

This is essentially the same as D, but it makes "like" sound like a definite action.  (This would make more sense on Facebook where "Like" is something that you either do or do not do.)

> C) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places liked mostly by people living in urban areas.

This would mean that most of the people who prefer rivers, mountains, and forests are urbanites.  ("mostly" is being applied to "by people [...]".)

> D) Rivers, mountains and forests are the places liked most by people living in urban areas.

This would mean that urbanites prefer rivers, mountains, and forests more than they prefer other kinds of places.  ("liked most" indicates highest preference.)